# Precision of Sin vs Cos functions in Fortran

Tags: floating-point, fortran, precision, gfortran

Consider the code,

```
PROGRAM TRIG_TEST
IMPLICIT NONE

DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: PI=4.D0*DATAN(1.0D)

print *, sin(PI/2.0), cos(PI/2.0)

END PROGRAM TRIG_TEST
```

Compiling with `gfortran` outputs,

```
1.0000000000000000 6.1232339957367660E-017
```

I am aware of the usual floating point issues but is there a reason why the `sin` function is identically 1, but the `cos` function is not identically zero?

Comment: What is the value of `episilon(1d0)` for your compiler?

Comment: The value is ~ 2.2e-16?

Comment: Sounds plausible.  Assume that both `sin` and `cos` are accurate to within `7E-017`.  That gives you the answer for `cos`.  `1-7E-017` is equal to `1.`  [You say you understand the "usual floating point issues".  Do you need this aspect explaining, or do you call this a slight oversight?]

Comment: You can avoid the multiplication in the definition of PI by using PI = ACOS(-1.d0). Intrinsic function like the trig functions do not need the double precision specific version. ATAN would be enough just like you used sin and cos instead of dsin and dcos. Fortran will link the correct version according to the arguments. Also to be formally correct, your literals should be double precision: print*, sin(PI/2.d0), cos(PI/2.d0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following assumes `double` is the IEEE 754 basic 64-bit binary format. Common implementations of the trigonometric routines are less accurate than the format supports. However, for this answer, let’s assume they return the most accurate results possible.

π cannot be exactly represented in `double`. The closest possible value is 884279719003555 / 281474976710656 or 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875. Let’s call this *p*.

The sine of *p*/2 is about 1 − 1.8747•10<sup>−33</sup>. The two values representable in `double` on either side of that are 1 and 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875, which is about 1 − 1.11•10<sup>−16</sup>. The closer of those is 1, so the closest representable value to sine of `p/2` is exactly 1.

The cosine of *p*/2 is about 6.123233995736765886•10<sup>−17</sup>. The closest value representable in `double` to that is 6.12323399573676603586882014729198302312846062338790031898128063403419218957424163818359375•10<sup>−17</sup>.

So the results you observed are the closest possible results to the true mathematical values.

Comment: In support of this answer, the interested reader can use `ieee_selected_real_kind()` to select a kind parameter for given desired characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at why the result from `sin` gives 1.  In your code

```
DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: PI=4.D0*DATAN(1.0D0)
```

This is a floating point approximation to the value of pi.  It's probably pretty close to the real value, but it isn't it.  Also, the `sin` function has errors in the evaluation of sin.  We hope those are small errors.

We expect that cos(pi/2) has value zero.  Your floating point calculation `cos(PI/2)` has an error of about `6.1232339957367660E-017` from the mathematical answer.  Let's assume that your sin calculation has a similar magnitude of error.

Now look at the value of `epsilon(0d)`.  This is the smallest number for which `1d0+epsilon(0d0)` is not equal to `1d0`.  The assumed error is much smaller than this number, in the model (for which you report "~ 2.2e-16").

So, `1` is the closest representable number to the real value of the floating point calculation.

Consider the program

```
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : real128, real64
  implicit none

  real(real64), parameter :: PI=4.D0*ATAN(1._real64)
  real(real128), parameter :: PI_approx = PI   ! Not 4*ATAN(1._real128)

  print *, SIN(PI/2), COS(PI/2)
  print *, SIN(PI_approx/2), COS(PI_approx/2)

end
```

This calculates (possibly) the sin of your `PI/2` but at a higher precision (using the same approximation for pi).  My compiler reports a value different from `1` in the second case, but the difference being much less than `epsilon(0._real64)`.

---

As a style point, in general it is best to avoid `datan` and use the generic `atan`.  `double precision` may also be replaced by appropriate kind parameters.  These are shown in my program above.